# Extend C++ project with CMakeList.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I'm trying to transform old project with Makefile to a modern one with CMakeLists.txt and GoogleTest framework but i can't handle the dependencies.
This is my Project structure

```
Project-LG
    src/
        app/
          main.cpp
          A.cpp
          A.hpp
          B.cpp
          B.hpp
          C.cpp
          C.hpp
          ...
        cpp-utils/
          D.cpp
          D.hpp
          E.hpp
          F.hpp
        json/
            json.hpp
        hiredis/    /*Makefile project*/
        orane2/     /*Makefile project*/
        rmr/        /*Makefile project*/
        spdlog/     /*Headers project with nested directories*/
        Makefile
```

And this is the "Project-LG" Makefile

```
CC=gcc
CPP=g++

SRCDIR = .
APPDIR = $(SRCDIR)/app
UTILSDIR = $(SRCDIR)/cpp-utils

TARGETDIR =./../out
OBJDIR =./../out/obj
APP_OBJDIR =$(OBJDIR)/app
UTILS_OBJDIR =$(OBJDIR)/cpp-utils

LIBSDIR = ./../libs

INCLUDE_FILE = \
    -Iapp \
    -Icpp-utils \
    -Irmr/si \
    -Irmr/si/si95 \
    -Irmr/common \
    -Ijson \
    -Iorane2 \
    -I. \
    -Ihiredis

SUBDIRS := \
    $(SRCDIR)/rmr \
    $(SRCDIR)/orane2 \
    $(SRCDIR)/hiredis

LFLAGS =
LIBS += -pthread -static-libstdc++ \
    -L$(LIBSDIR) -l:librmr.a -l:liborane2.a -l:hiredis.a

XAPP_NAME_STR := '"app-lg"'

CFLAGS += -Wall -g -O2 -DXAPP_NAME=$(XAPP_NAME_STR) $(INCLUDE_FILE)
CPPFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -std=c++17

APP_EXE ?= xapp

APP_SOURCES := $(shell find $(APPDIR) -maxdepth 1 -name '*.cpp' -printf '%f\n')
UTILS_SOURCES := $(shell find $(UTILSDIR) -maxdepth 1 -name '*.cpp' -printf '%f\n')

APP_OBJS := $(addprefix $(APP_OBJDIR)/, $(APP_SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o))
UTILS_OBJS := $(addprefix $(UTILS_OBJDIR)/, $(UTILS_SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o))

.SUFFIXES: .c~.o

.PHONY: all $(SUBDIRS) clean

all: $(SUBDIRS) $(APP_EXE)

$(APP_EXE): $(APP_OBJS) $(UTILS_OBJS)
    @mkdir -p $(TARGETDIR)
    @mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $(APP_OBJS) $(UTILS_OBJS) $(LIBS) -o $(TARGETDIR)/$@

$(APP_OBJDIR)/%.o : $(APPDIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    @mkdir -p $(APP_OBJDIR)
    $(CPP) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(UTILS_OBJDIR)/%.o : $(UTILSDIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    @mkdir -p $(UTILS_OBJDIR)
    $(CPP) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGETDIR)
```

It was difficult to figure out how to call the Makefile from CMake and how to add the GoogleTest framework with all its dependencies
Please accept my thanks for your time.

Comment: There is more than one question asked here (at least that's what I think; the problem statement isn't very clear): "How do I add GoogleTest?" and "How do I build the make file project from my CMake project?" Both seem to be unrelated problems so it would be preferrable to start 2 "question threads" for those. Btw: Honestly at this level of complexity of the makefiles I'd rather create cmake equivalents of those.

Comment: Hey @fabian, Thank you for answering.
You are right, I didn't express my self as needed.
I don't care about GTest, more about converting this makefile to CMakeLists

Comment: How familiar are you with CMake? This is quite a sizeable project and it would definitely be easier to start with one of the subprojects first. Normally you'd have a CMakeLists for each and simply adding them to the top-level one is then enough to obtain the information for building and linking them.